# Machine with current logged on user

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have this task at work that I need to get the users that are currently logged into some machines.
I have this spreadsheet, that has all the machine names, but I want to do a query that I can get all the users that are assigned to those machines.
Here is what I currently have but it is not working out for me:

```
$computers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\book1.xlsx"

for-each ( $computer in $computers ) {
  $uda = Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $computer.Name 
  
  if ( ($uda.UniqueUserName).count -gt 1 ) { 
      foreach ( $user in $uda.UniqueUserName ) { 
          Write-Host $uda.ResourceName[1] $user
      }
  }
  else {
      write-host $uda.ResourceName $uda.UniqueUserName
  } 
  
  export-csv -path C:\temp\book1.xlsx
}
```

Any help would be apricated

Comment: $computers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\book1.xlsx"

for-each ( $computer in $computers )
{
  $uda = Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -DeviceName $computer.Name
  
  if ( ($uda.UniqueUserName).count -gt 1 )
  {
    foreach ( $user in $uda.UniqueUserName )
    {
      Write-Host $uda.ResourceName[1] $user
    }
  }
  else
  {
    write-host $uda.ResourceName $uda.UniqueUserName
  }
  export-csv -path C:\temp\book1.xlsx
}

Comment: Please edit any code updates into the question and elaborate on what "not working out for me" means.  At a glance, I can see that you're using `*-Csv` cmdlets with non-CSV (`.xlsx`) files, and also you're not passing any data to `export-csv`.

Comment: it is telling me cannot validate argument on parameter 'DeviceName'. The argument is null or empty. Even if I did with a .csv file the same error would pop up.

Comment: I assume your CSV file has a `Name` column?  It'd be helpful to include the first few lines of that file.  Does every row have a value for that field?  Does it fail on the very first row?  Also, your outermost loop is `for-each` when it should be `foreach`.

Comment: so the first column has machine names at the top and a bunch of computer names, the second column has username at the top and nothing underneath. Everytime run that script i get that error message.
What I want the script to do is to get the username that is associated to that machine and add it to the second column.